# Regex: find pattern UNLESS pattern contains a hashtag

Tags: regex

```
string1 = "dog walked"
string2 = "#dog walked"

substring = "dog"
```

I want to find "dog" in string1 but not string2. I thought `[^#]dog` would work but it doesn't match string1 unless it becomes " dog walked".

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What tool are you using the regex with?

Comment: A negative lookbehind will do what you're after, e.g. [`(?<!#)dog`](https://regex101.com/r/bU6mU0/1)

Comment: just in rails, so string1[/[^#]#{substring}/].present?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've been looking and trying in Rubular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, a negative lookbehind would be a solution (amongst others, that is):

```
(?<!#)dog
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bU6mU0/1).

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what I wanted